# How to run a Spring Boot application in Minikube?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube

I want to run [this Spring Boot application](https://github.com/dptij/example-1) inside Minikube so that I can reach port `8080` in my browser (once the application is running).

To do so, I do following steps.

1. Start Docker.
2. Run `mvn spring-boot:build-image`.
3. Start Minikube using `minikube start`.
4. Create a Minikube deployment using `kubectl create deployment example-1-engine-1 --image=example-1-engine-1`.
5. Expose port 8080 using `kubectl expose deployment example-1-engine-1 --type=NodePort --port=8080` and `kubectl port-forward service/example-1-engine-1 8080:8080`.
6. Start the appliation in Minikube.
7. Start the application in Minikube using `minikube service example-1-engine-1`.

Following output appears:

[image: Output of Minikube in the command line]

However, the browser cannot open the web application on port 8080 (browser cannot connect to the application at http://127.0.0.1:50947/).

**What am I doing wrong and how can I make sure that the application in question runs inside Minikube and I can access the web application at port 8080?**

**Update 1:** Here is the output of `kubectl get pods`:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXX>kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
example-1-engine-1-d9fc48785-zdvkf   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          2d18h
hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-wj6c2      1/1     Running            1          5d
```

**Update 2:** I tried to enter `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`. For this purpose, I first opened the shell of Minikube container in Docker.

[image: Screenshot of the button for opening the shell in Minikube]

In the window that appeared thereafter, I entered `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)` and got the response `minikube: not found`.

[image: Screenshot of the error message "minikube: not found"]

Comment: Could you show the output of `kubectl get pods`, I am assuming the application is not deployed in minikube.

Comment: `minikube service --url <service-name>` ; then try with the output.

Comment: @Thomas See update 1.

Comment: Yes, confirms my suspicions, see answer from matt_j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two possible issues with your case.

#### 1. Using a locally built Docker image

You want to run locally built Docker image in Kubernetes, but it doesn't work out-of-the-box.
Generally, you have two options:

1. Use `docker image push` command to share your image to the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) registry or to a self-hosted one as described in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/).
2. Use `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command to point your terminal to use the docker daemon inside minikube as described in the [minikube documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env).

#### 2. Using a Docker image with a specific tag

As I can see, your image has specific tag `1.0-SNAPSHOT`:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG                     
example-1-engine-1                        1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

You need to specify this tag in your `kubectl create deployment` command:

```
$ kubectl create deployment example-1-engine-1 --image=example-1-engine-1:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

---

I've deployed your [Spring Boot application](https://github.com/dptij/example-1), to show that it works as expected for me.

First, to point my terminal to use the docker daemon inside minikube I ran:

```
$ eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

Then I created Docker image and deployed `example-1-engine-1` app:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:build-image
...
[INFO] Successfully built image 'docker.io/library/example-1-engine-1:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...

$ kubectl create deployment example-1-engine-1 --image=example-1-engine-1:1.0-SNAPSHOT
deployment.apps/example-1-engine-1 created

$ kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
example-1-engine-1-c98f8c569-xq2cv   1/1     Running   0          13s
```

Finally, I exposed the `example-1-engine-1` `Deployment` as in your example:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment example-1-engine-1 --type=NodePort --port=8080
service/example-1-engine-1 exposed

$ kubectl port-forward service/example-1-engine-1 8080:8080
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080

$ minikube service example-1-engine-1
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |        NAME        | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | example-1-engine-1 |        8080 | http://192.168.49.2:32766 |
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
Opening service default/example-1-engine-1 in default browser...
```

In the open browser tab, I saw:

[image]

Additionally, I saw the same page at `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

---

Unfortunately, I don't have Windows machine (as in your example) and I used Linux instead, so I wasn't able to exactly reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please look at update 2 and tell me, if you see any obvious errors.

Comment: The `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command should be run in the host machine's terminal (the same terminal you are running e.g. `minikube start` or `kubectl get pods`) not inside minikube.

Comment: I could not find this command under Windows. However, I managed to use the other approach you proposed (pushing to Docker Hub) and it seems to work. Thanks!